# Is there an EVM based blockchain that allows to receive a stable coin in msg.value?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, tokens, contract-design

I am looking for a EVM based network (like Polygon, Fantom , etc..) that allows to receive USDT, USDC or any stable coin as payment in `msg.value` function

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

There is the gnosis chain that uses xDai as a native token

https://docs.gnosischain.com/specs/

Comment: Thanks! Let me read about it.
I am cautious with these stable projects since what happened with Terra/luna. What do you think about it?

Comment: It's good imo, Gnosis is reputable and xDai is DAI behing the scene. Some projects are using like POAP